# VGA DVI to HDTV HDMI intermittent output problem

Tags: hdmi, dvi, hdtv

I have a PC connected to my 42" HDTV.

In my PC I have an nVidia 8600 GT video card with two DVI outputs and it is currently connected to my HDTV with a VGA to VGA cable that connects to the graphics card with a DVI to VGA converter. That works fine.

PowerDVD refuses to playback BluRay discs through this analog connection and keeps requiring a digital connection so trying to solve that and thinking that I might get a better signal using a DVI to HDMI cable to connect from Graphics' card DVI port directly to HDMI port on my TV I purchased a cable from monoprice (if relevant) and connected PC to HDTV that way.

The result is an intermittent signal which is off and on every few seconds in equal intervals...

-The cable appears to be of good quality like all the other cables I purchased from mono and never had any problems with.

-My cable box is connected to the HDTV using an HDMI to HDMI cable and that works fine so the HDMI ports on my HDTV are not a problem.

-When I connect to HDTV using VGA to VGA cable and the DVI to VGA converter I have zero problems so I think that eliminates my graphics card.

-I also have an DVI to HDMI converter which I tried attaching to the DVI port on my graphics card and connecting to my HDTV with a HDMI to HDMI cable but that results in no signal at all.

Anyway, I'm stuck and have no idea how to troubleshoot further, the only thing that comes to mind is buying another DVI to HDMI cable to make sure that it is not the cable itself but don't feel like wasting more money...

Any ideas, suggestions, new troubleshooting steps are welcome...

Comment: When using the DVI to HDMI cable, open your nVidia control panel and check the HDCP status.  Is everything correct?  Does it stay connected when you play a BluRay?

Comment: Your system is HDCP-Capable, that's all I see in "View HDCP status"...